# Embed Visualforce Page into Native Mobile app as Hybrid page

Tags: visualforce, mobile, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, oauth, salesforce-sdk-hybrid

We have developed a native iOS mobile app that connects to Salesforce, users login through this native app using OAuth user-agent flow and a connected App.

This all works fine.

We are now trying to embed an authenticated visualforce page into the app in a hybrid pattern. As the user is already authenticated we want to re-use this to access the visualforce page.

The following extract from this [document](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2011/09/using-oauth-2-0-with-visualforce-in-winter-12.html) says that we can do this by appending &oauth_token to the url. I have already added visualforce to the scope of the connected app. **However this does not seem to work as we are always redirected to login.salesforce.com. The document is a little dated and I can find no other postings on this matter. Does anyone have more detail or an updated approach.**

> Once the user logs in successfully, you can then append the OAuth access token to a VF URL and direct users to it (for e.g. ‘https://c.cs0.visual.force.com/apex/HelloWorld?oauth_token=’)

Comment: Do you have the correct instance URL, replace `https://c.cs0.visual.force.com` with your Salesforce instance URL?

Comment: Im using the my.salesforce url as this is the url that is returned in the oauth response. **Note my VF is in a managed package so the page also has a namespace. To the end of this url I add some other parameters and then the &oauth_token=xxx
https://ee-test-eposly.my.salesforce.com/apex/mpos__EposProductInfo